# java extends javax.swing.jframe and inputverifier

Tags: java, inner-classes, inputverifier

I have need
to extends javax.swing.jframe and inputverifier. Can i resilienza this problema? ?? I try to use more classes But this doesn't work. Can I use a inner class?

```
Public class framePrincial extends     javax.swing.jframe {
Abstract verifica extends inputverifier  {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can use an inner class. You cannot extend more than one class. You can extend one class and implement as many interfaces as you like. There is no way to tell you a good way to do what you want to do without knowing what you want to do.

Comment: I ask the best soluto to sole my problem

Comment: My point is that we don't know what your problem is -- you are asking how to do things with the language that indicate you aren't familiar with the language; you could do a great deal of that without getting any help solving your problem. Say what you want to do and then what your language difficulty is. Otherwise it's just a waste of time.